# How do you order variables for an orthogonalized irf in R?

Tags: r, var

I'm using the vars package and the `irf()` function and setting `ortho = TRUE`, but I'm not exactly sure if it's doing anything.

How would I define a specific order for my VAR model?

Comment: Use `TRUE` instead of `True`.

Comment: Slight typo in the post, I used TRUE. If I used True instead I'd get a syntax error.